# Lightbox / Fancybox iframe to show certain div r content

Tags: jquery, fancybox, lightbox

What im trying to achieve:

User is visiting my website, clicks on a product and an iframe html page will show bigger images of the product with text along side.

Now if someone visits that direct iframe html link they will only see the box of the product, not the rest of the website.

So i've tried to make the iframe display the div on its own using ajax / datafilter, it worked in firefox not in chrome.

tried window scrollTo, worked in chrome not in firefox.

Does anyone have an alternative?

Comment: can you use jsfiddle.net to display your code?

Comment: if I understood right, your issue is more "outside" of the fancybox than "inside" of fancybox? did you already manage to show the wanted `div` **inside** fancybox?